# decorators to make a sequential set of tasks in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, distributed-computing, pipeline

I am writing a program that executes a set of tasks sequentially. Each task is a function that outputs a new file, but any given task should not execute if the filename already exists. I find myself writing this kind of code over and over again:

```
task1_fname = task1()
# come up with filename for next task
task2_fname = "task2.txt"
if not os.path.isfile(task2_fname):
  # task2 might depend on task1's output, so it gets task1's filename
  task2(task1_fname)
task3_fname = "task3.txt"
if not os.path.isfile(task3_fname):
  task3(...)
```

The basic idea is that if a file is present (and ideally nonempty) then you should not execute the task that generates this file.

What's the best Pythonic way to express this without having to write `os.path.isfile` calls everytime? Could decorators express this more concisely? Or something along the lines of:

```
with task2(task1_fname):
  # continue to next task
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
def preserve_output(f):
    def wrap(input, output):
        if not os.path.isfile(output):
            f(input, output)
    return wrap

@preserve_output
def task1(input, output):
    ...

@preserve_output
def task2(input, output):
    ...

task1('input', 'output_1')
task2('output_1', 'output_2')
task3('output_2', 'output_3') etc
```